# Try-Catch block impairing code

Tags: c#, udp, try-catch, udpclient

I wrote a simple UDP framework, and it worked just fine. Upon wrapping my code in a try/catch block the send function stopped working - there were no compiler or runtime errors and when I removed the try/catch statement, the send function began working again.

All of my other methods, including the receive method, seem to have remained unaffected by the try/catch statement. Consider the code below:

```
public static AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(SendCallback);

public static void Send(string data) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        socket.BeginSend(bytes, bytes.Length, callback, socket);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e.Message);
    }
}

public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        socket.EndSend(ar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm curious as to why this happened.

Comment: Try catch wont cause an exception by it self, the code inside the catch block will never get run unless there is an exception. Upon knowing this, then its obvious there is a problem somewhere else that is throwing the exception. Quick question, is this a console application?

Comment: why do you declare "new AsyncCallback(SendCallback)" instead of using SendCallback directly?

Comment: Anyway I think you're catching only exceptions durinf the "Begin" and "End" phase of the communication because it's an asynchronous method, and it will be executed in a second thread. Maybe you need to call SendAsync or a similiar method using "await" so you can catch exceptions.

Comment: @TheGeneral The server is a console application, however the client (where this problem happened) is in Unity.

Comment: @Francesco Yes, I should be caching the callback - I've edited the question.

Comment: @BillBaits Is there any feedback from ar.AsyncState? 
Unity has also a Debug.Log method to write data directly to the editor console.